# 404 not found on WCF REST service

Tags: .net, rest, wcf, http-status-code-404

I'have configured REST on WCF service. I have an other project working like this  and copied from to my project all config and things. But when I run it, rest method and /web page not found.

Web.config:

```
> <appSettings>
>     <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />   </appSettings>   <system.web>
>     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
>     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>   </system.web>   <system.serviceModel>
>     <services>
>       <service name="WcfRestTest.Service1">
>         <clear />
>         <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RFEndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
>           contract="WcfRestTest.IService1" listenUriMode="Explicit">
>         </endpoint>
>       </service>
>     </services>
>     <behaviors>
>       <endpointBehaviors>
>         <behavior name="RFEndPointBehavior"  >
>           <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
>         </behavior>
>       </endpointBehaviors>
>     </behaviors>
>     <protocolMapping>
>       <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
>     </protocolMapping>
>     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />   </system.serviceModel>  
> <system.webServer>
>     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
>     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
```

> 

Service Class:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public List<Student> GetStudentDetails()
    {
        List<Student> stuList = new List<Student>();
        stuList.Add(new Student { ID = "1", Name = "Test" });
        return stuList;
    }
}
```

Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Students", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Student> GetStudentDetails();
    }

[DataContract]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I coped you code segments and found it works well. In my opinion, there is something wrong with the address you accessed.
For the WCF Rest service hosted in IIS, we are supposed to use the IIS base address and the UriTemplate property,

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Students", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

For example, here is a below site binding in IIS.
[image]
The service base address is http://MyIP:11000/service1.svc, and the operation should be routed by using http://MyIP:11000/service1.svc/Students.
One more thing must be noted is that the service usually has a relative address. Assumed that there is a below definition.

```
<endpoint address="myservice" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" listenUriMode="Explicit"></endpoint>
```

It should also be taken into account.
http://MyIP:11000/service1.svc/myservice/Students 
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

**Updated**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfRestTest.Service1">
    <clear />
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RFEndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="WcfRestTest.IService1" listenUriMode="Explicit">
    </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRestTest.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="RFEndPointBehavior" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mybinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RFEndPointBehavior"  >
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: Hello again, thanks for answer, I try it on visual stuido (iis express), I have not publish it IIS yet. Relative address doesn't work too. Which project type you created for this example Abraham?

Comment: I use the WCF service application project template in VS2017. what is the base address that IIS express provided?

Comment: If project template is wcf service application there is no problem it works. But other web project type I can serve wcf services (i have another project alive) but i can't access rest service methods

Comment: You could post the complete project type and testing process, I will try to reproduce the issue.
On my side, when I use the web application template and add a WCF service item (Ajax enabled), it also works properly. One thing needs to mention is that there is not a service interface under this scenario.

Comment: Hi Abraham, here is the sample project. Thanks for help.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag9IW3o-pNntoagml6n1zIYypyvv5g?e=DsNLm3

Comment: On my side, the service works well over HTTP. Do you mean that the service over https works improperly? we need to add an https service endpoint. please refer to  the updated reply.

Comment: Yes, I try only https, over HTTP, service doens't response (including svc).